# How to move button little up?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to move all these buttons a little up to top, like about 50dp.
here is my code for first button

```
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            android:text="Load game"
            android:textColor="#C3C3C3"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"`
to your layout where are your all buttons

Answer (score 0):

padding property is used to set the internal of the widget (for example paddingtop=10 then your text in button will be 10px below in the rect of button ) 
margine property is relatived to the Parent ViewGroup of the widget

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your buttons in a linear layout and set margin or padding to it like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchLinearLayout"
            android:paddingTop="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```